# center of a polygon created with mapbox

Tags: javascript, polygon, mapbox

I would like to know how to calculate the centre of a polygon created with this code from Mapbox: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/show-polygon-area/
I would like to place a marker on the centre of the polygon after it's been created.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried to use the following : var center = e.layer.bounds.getCenter(); But it doesn't work. I have found other scripts to calculate the center of a polygon, but I'm not sure where to find the polygon created

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To calculate the center of a polygon you first need to get it's bounds, that can be done using the `getBounds` method of `L.Polygon` which it enherits from `L.Polyline`:

> Returns the LatLngBounds of the polyline.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline-getbounds

It returns a `L.LatLngBounds` object which has a `getCenter` method:

> Returns the center point of the bounds

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-getcenter

It returns a `L.LatLng` object which you can use to create a `L.Marker`:

```
var polygon = new L.Polygon(coordinates).addTo(map);

var bounds = polygon.getBounds();

var center = bounds.getCenter();

var marker = new L.Marker(center).addTo(map);
```

Or you can shorthand it:

```
var polygon = new L.Polygon(coordinates).addTo(map);

var marker = new L.Marker(polygon.getBounds().getCenter()).addTo(map);
```

Using that in the Mapbox example would look something like this:

```
function showPolygonArea(e) {
    featureGroup.clearLayers();
    featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);

    // Here 'e.layer' holds the L.Polygon instance:
    new L.Marker(e.layer.getBounds().getCenter()).addTo(featureGroup);

    e.layer.bindPopup((LGeo.area(e.layer) / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' km<sup>2</sup>');
    e.layer.openPopup();
}
```

Comment: Thanks iH8, how can I get the coordinates of the created polygone from the mapbox sample code? That's where I'm lost, I cannot find any L.Polygon on that piece of code. https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/show-polygon-area/ Is there a way to get the coordinates from here: function showPolygonAreaEdited(e) {
  e.layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    showPolygonArea({ layer: layer });
  });

Comment: I'll append a L.Draw usecase to my answer

Comment: oh, ic, do you mean something like this?: var marker = new L.Marker(L.Draw.getBounds().getCenter()).addTo(map);

Comment: No, that won't work, check my updated answer. `new L.Marker(e.layer.getBounds().getCenter()).addTo(featureGroup);` is what you need to do in the `showPolygonArea` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use turf `library.turf.center(features)` gives you a point feature at the absolute center point of all input features. where features in your case will be the polygon selected which you can get using `mapboxDraw.getAll()`